# .bat Wildcard for a Folder

Tags: batch-file

How do you use wildcards in a Folder?

```
7z x -oS:\Technology\FEFTP\* S:\Technology\FEFTP\*.zip

ren S:\Technology\FEFTP\Export_Job9_04-08-2014_16-24(wildcardthis) TestFolderRename 

ren S:\Technology\FEFTP\TestFolderRename\*.CSV test1.csv

move S:\Technology\FEFTP\TestFolderRename\*.CSV S:\Technology\FEFTP\Test
```

What would be the best way to go about this?
I need a wildcard to replace Export_Job9_04-08-2014_16-24.
It will be the only thing in the folder so it does not need to be that specific.
I tried *E, E?, but that did not work. What is the proper method to use?

Comment: wildcards are not supported when REN is used over folders: http://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards#475875

Comment: You can check MOVE where the source can contain wildcard - http://ss64.com/nt/move.html

Comment: @npocmaka when using the move command does it allow you to specify a destination for the new file. Is this what this code is doing MOVE g:\department\oldfile.wp "c:\Files to Convert\newfile.doc".

I guess my question is how do you use wildcards with move to rename a sub directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /d %%a in ("S:\Technology\FEFTP\Export*") do ren "%%~fa" TestFolderRename
```

Obviously, it will only work if (as stated) you have only one `Export*` folder (you can not rename two folders to the same name), and if `TestFolderRename` does not exist (name collision).